# Function erroring out when calling another function

Tags: python, function

I'm getting the following error when calling a function from another function:

`TypeError: 'GLMResultsWrapper' object is not callable`

I get the error at the `coeffs = model_results(model_results)` line below.

This is another function that runs error free outside of the `table_to_graph` function.  The model_results function takes the summary output from a `statsmodel` model and puts it into a data frame.

The table_to_graph function joins that dataframe to another table that is the `df` in the input.  table_to_graph function below.

The ultimate function is the following:

```
# Add into table generation table
def table_to_graph(model_results, df):
    '''
    #function that combines rating tables and model summary

    '''
    coeffs = model_results(model_results)

    try:
        df['key'] = df['variable']+"_"+df['level']
        df = pd.merge(df, coeffs, left_on = 'key', right_on = 'index', how = 'left')
        df['factor'] = np.exp(df[factor])
        df['factor'].fillna(1, inplace = True)
        df['error_up'] = np.exp(df[error_up])
        df['error_down'] = np.exp(df[error_down])
        #title2 = title1

        df = df[['model', 'variable', 'level', 'total_incurred', 'total_count', 'cmeu', 'factor', 'error_up', 'error_down'
                 , 'pricing_model_1_p_values']]

        return df

        #df1 = df1.append(df)

    except:

        #df['level'] = df['level'].astype('str')
        df['key'] = df['variable']+"_"+df['level'].astype('str')
        df['level'] = df['level'].astype('int')
        df = pd.merge(df, coeffs, left_on = 'key', right_on = 'index', how = 'left')
        df['factor'] = np.exp(df[factor])
        df['factor'].fillna(1, inplace = True)
        df['error_up'] = np.exp(df[error_up])
        df['error_down'] = np.exp(df[error_down])

        df = df[['model', 'variable', 'level', 'total_incurred', 'total_count', 'cmeu', 'factor', 'error_up'
             , 'error_down', 'pricing_model_1_p_values']]

        #df1 = df1.append(df)


        return df
```

model_results function below:

```
def model_results(model_results):
    '''
    function that puts model parameters into a data frame

    '''

    df = pd.DataFrame(model_results.params, columns = ['factor'])
    df['error_down'] = model_results.conf_int()[0]
    df['error_up'] = model_results.conf_int()[1]
    df['standard_error'] = model_results.bse
    df['pvalues'] = round(model_results.pvalues, 3)
    df.reset_index(inplace = True)
    return df
```

Comment: So your "results" model_results are inserted into a function that is also exactly called model_results? This will not work, name either the results differently or the function

Comment: That worked! Thanks. If you want to post it as a solution I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling the function you have defined as model_results but instead are "calling" the model_results data on the model_results data. This is why you get the error that the object is not callable.

Change either the function name or the name of the model_results data to something else, this will allow python to make a distinction between the two and do what you want it to do. Which is call the **function** model_results on the model_results **data**.